# POST to url from Parse.com cloud code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

How do I `POST` to external `url` in `Parse.com` from the `cloud`?

I looked around but there seems to be nothing in `Parse.com`'s forums, and the generic `javascript` solution involves creating a `form` object:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
```

which is obviously not the solution I need because I need to submit the url from the server (`cloud code`.)

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
var url = "http://servername/v1/submit?";
var params = "lm_form=33333&lm_key=55555&fld_28226=name"
url = url + params;
var response = submitToUrl(url);
```

So the question is, what does `submitToUrl` look like?

EDIT: following Wain's answer I'm using this:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',

    success: function(resp) {
        console.log("request submited " + resp);
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      console.log('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }            
});
```

with the `url` being the `url + params` from above. It triggers the `success` method but with `400 error code.`

Submitting the same `url` through the browser window works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Can't you use an Ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: ...,
    method: 'POST',
    header:{
        ...
    },
    body:{
        ...
    }
}
```

(Either using promises or callbacks to handle the response)

It isn't clear from the question wether your parameters should be in the URL or the body, for POST it would usually be the body...

Comment: Thanks, could you add a couple of parameters to the body section? Just so I don't need to worry about the syntax.

Comment: Using  a url like this: 'servername/v1/submit?fld_28226=test&fld_28227=000000000&fld_30064=carrier&fld_29603=19.9' without adding header or body submits the url, but comes back with 400 response code. Submitting the same url through the browser address line works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: A browser does a GET, not a POST. Are you sure you really want to be POSTing?

Comment: Yes, I want to do a POST. But in any case I tried and changed it to GET with the same result: the error block is called, with 400 response code.

Comment: Does the server tell you what it isn't happy with in the request?

Comment: No :( all I get is the response code 400. Maybe I should try to add a body block to the httpRequest and put the parameters in there? Although  from the docs it seems like it would submit the same url + params anyway.

Comment: My url included two word entries with space and it looks like I need to encode the url:  url = encodeURI(url); It's working now.

Comment: Good stuff, just to add that if you do add body content be sure to add a Content-Type header